# Draw Polylines and Polygons based on MongoDB stored GeoJson Coordinates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, google-maps, geojson

I'm realizing an application which is supposed to show on a Google Map `Points`, `LineStrings` and `Polygons`.

I'm using a `Mongoose` schema which allows those 3 kind of data to get stored and I'm able to post all of them with no problems.

I'm already able to draw `Points` since they have only 1 entry per `lat, lng` pair, but, I'm really struggling with understanding how to fetch `LineString` and `Polygon` `lat, lng` couples from the db, store them in a matrix and then drawing these object into the map.

This is what I'm trying to do for **LineStrings**:

```
var valueToPush = [];

// Loop through all of the JSON entries provided in the response
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var user = response[i];

      if (user.location.type === "LineString") {

         for (var j = 0; j < user.location.coordinates.length; j++) {

             valueToPush[j] = user.location.coordinates[j];
             valueToPush[j+1] = user.location.coordinates[j+1];
          }
       }

   return valueToPush;
};

console.log(valueToPush); //Printing the right LineString Points
```

And this is how I'm trying to draw **LineStrings**:

```
var initialize = function() {

  valueToPush.forEach(function(){
     var myPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  path: parseFloat(valueToPush),
                  geodesic: true,
                  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                  strokeWeight: 2
      });

      myPath.setMap(map);
  });
}
```

But from the latter i get `InvalidValueError: not an Array js?key=myKey`

This is my **Mongoose Schema**:

```
// Pulls Mongoose dependency for creating schemas
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var GeoJSON  = require('geojson');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var LocationSchema = new Schema({
                                    name: {type: String, required: true},
                                    location: {
                                      type: {type : String, required: true},
                                      coordinates : [Schema.Types.Mixed]
                                    },
                                    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
                                    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the created_at parameter equal to the current time
LocationSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if(!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now
    }
    next();
});

// Indexes this schema in 2dsphere format (critical for running proximity searches)
LocationSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('mean-locations', LocationSchema);
```

And this is how I post a new LineString using **Postman**:

```
{
  "name": "FirstPolyline",
  "location": {
                            "type":"LineString",
                            "coordinates": 
                                            [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0] ]

  }
}
```

**What Am I doing wrong? How Can I fix this?**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create a cycle that iterates over all the items in the `response` array. Then depending on the item's location type, call an appropriate function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var item = response[i];
    if (item.location.type === "LineString") {
       addPolyline(item.location.coordinates, map);
    }else if(item.location.type === "Polygon") {
       addPolygon(item.location.coordinates, map);
    }
}
```

function for adding lineString would look like this. Use `google.maps.Polyline` object.

```
function addPolyline(coords, map){
    var polyline_coordinates = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
        polyline_coordinates.push({lat: coords[i][0], lng: coords[i][1]});
    }
    var new_polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path: polyline_coordinates,
       geodesic: true,
       strokeColor: '#FF0000',
       strokeOpacity: 1.0,
       strokeWeight: 2
    });
    new_polyline.setMap(map);
}
```

Similarly for polygons using `google.maps.Polygon` object.

```
function addPolygon(coords, map){
    var polygon_coordinates = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
        polygon_coordinates.push({lat: parseFloat(coords[i][0]), lng: parseFloat(coords[i][1])});
    }
    var new_polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
       path: polygon_coordinates,
       geodesic: true,
       strokeColor: '#FF0000',
       strokeOpacity: 1.0,
       strokeWeight: 2,
       fillColor: '#FF0000',
       fillOpacity: 0.5
    });
    new_polygon.setMap(map);
}
```

In both cases you need to create a path array. Path array is an array of objects like `path:MVCArray<LatLng>|Array<LatLng|LatLngLiteral>`. Check [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polygon).

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I'll be home. Thank you.

Comment: Calling `new_polyline.setMap(map);` gives `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map`. Any idea?

Comment: Where and how do you initialize your `map` ? Can you share that part of the code? You need to pass the variable which references the `map` object as a second parameter to `addPolygon` and `addPolyline` functions.

Comment: That's my code snippet https://gist.github.com/AndreaM16/32714948ab553aeb9d0281d623b305e5

Comment: Your code is very chaotic and from the part you shared it's not clear, in what order and how do you call `convertToMapPoints` and `initialize` functions. But to make this work you need to call `initialize` function BEFORE `convertToMapPoints` AND make variable `var map;` global (put it out of the `initialize` function) OR somehow pass it to `convertToMapPoints` function.

Comment: Thank you, It is working now! I only have one problem, don't know why but now I have multiple initial markers.

Comment: I mean, instead of having a single marker at the initial location (my location), I have 3 of them.

Comment: I think the change you made resulted in you calling `initialize` function multiple times now. Just make sure that it is called only once, maybe put some variable there that get's set to `true` when it was called and check if the variable is true, don't execute the code in the function.

Comment: Polygon won't get drawn. Your `for` needs `lng: coords[i][1]` but, even after this correction, if I log it I always get the same value (the first pair `lat, lng` of the Polygon).

Comment: Thanks, for the correction. That's weird though, probably something wrong with `location.coordinates` data. Did you try to log those?

Comment: They are ok. LineStrings get drawn properly. Instead, when trying to fetch polygons, logs always print the first `lat` value.

Comment: I don't get why it is not working since `Polygon Data` is pretty much equals to `LineString Data`, they are both coordinates arrays.

Comment: so `polygon_coordinates` is full of the same coordinates? I don't see anything what could cause this in my code. Try to print `coords` array at the start of the `addPolygon` function. Maybe there's something wrong with that.

Comment: Tried and `Coords` has the right data. I can see all the points stored in the polygon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113857/discussion-between-matej-p-and-andream16).